# Cannot modify a value in a Soy template

Tags: google-closure, google-closure-templates

```
{let $first: 10 /} // this is a single line soy comment
  {if $first > 5 }
  {$first}<br/>
  {let $first:$first-1 /}
  {/if}
{$first}
```

I tried this, and it prints: 10 10

Ideally, it should print: 10 9 ..

Can you please identify what's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you cannot really overwrite the value of `$first`. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/commands#let) states local variables defined by `let` are not modifiable. This is because whenever you alias a value with `let`, a new variable is created in the compiled output. Moreover, the scoping rules of soy expressions aren't the same as in Javascript (but you could think of `{let}` having similar semantics to ECMAScript 6's `let` statement, that is, non-hoisted, block-scoped).

In your code:

```
{let $first: 10 /}           /* 1 */
{if $first > 5}
  {$first}<br/>
  {let $first¹: $first-1 /}  /* 2 */
                             /* 3 */
{/if}
{$first}                     /* 4 */
```

what's happening is:

- In (1), `$first` is an alias for the value `10`. A variable is introduced to hold this value.
- In (2):

  **Right hand:** `$first` takes its value from (1), because it is defined in a parent block.

  **Left hand:** `$first¹` is being aliased to the value resulting from `$first` - 1 = 10 - 1 = 9. Because the definition of `$first` can't be overwritten, a new variable is introduced, different from (1). There are two things to note:

  a. The value for `$first¹` is 9, but it's *never* read in this snippet.

  b. `$first¹` only "lives" within the block it was defined, that is, inside `{if...}`. In fact, if you were to insert `{$first}` in (3), it would output 9.
- In (4), the value of `$first¹`, being out of the scope introduced by the `{if}` block, can no longer be read, so `$first` from (1) is the only one visible, yielding 10. It makes use of the same variable as (1) in the compiled output.